# Get the Name of a MobileConnect message as an AMPScript variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, mobileconnect

I'm building a "master sent log", which is essentially a DE that captures info about all email and sms messages sent from Marketing Cloud.

It captures this using AMPScript in the email that uses a `UpdateDE()` or `InsertData()` function. As part of this I set a bunch of variables to save to the DE at send time.

I want to be able to save the Name of the sms message to the DE. However, I can't find an ampscript variable for the message name.

For emails, the variable is *emailname_*

Is there an equivalent for SMS messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's not possible through any available Data Views, but since the `MessageID` is available through [**SMSMessageTracking**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view, you can check with your AE to check with SF internal architect team about this requirement. It's a paid service, but they may be able to build you a custom data view that contains the SMS message name value.

However - as an alternative you can prepare and use [**SMS Message Detail**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_sms_message_detail_report.htm&type=5) report that has the column `MessageName`. This way you can automate the report to FTP and import it to a Data Extension with Automation Studio, then use SQL queries to join it up with results from SMS Data Views.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at those options.